# Unlock other levels/maps in Nintendo land Wii U

Tags: nintendo-land

I am playing the new Nintendo land game on the Wii U and getting frustrated with just 2/3 maps for each mini game?

Is there some way to open more levels for each mini game?

Comment: sad face that nobody has an answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can unlock the following extra stages:

- Pikmin Adventure

  - Challenge maps: Complete all maps (in single or multiplayer) and you'll earn access to 6 extra, harder maps which can be played solo or co op.
  - Versus maps: Play 5 games on each level to unlock the next challenge level. There's only 3 levels that I'm aware of. You can unlock this with a single player using both wiimote and gamepad, just wait for the clock to run out 5 times.
- Luigi's Ghost Mansion:  Play 20 games. Which level you play doesn't matter. Quickest way to do this is to just kill the ghost immediately with the flashlight. A single player (with a Wiimote AND gamepad) is all you need to unlock, too, so you can spare your friends the grief of grinding if you don't want to play 20 levels organically.

There might be more I don't know of yet. I believe if you beat the courses in Donkey Kong's Crash Course a number of times you'll unlock more courses, but I haven't beaten the first course yet.

Answer (score 1):

If you play Luigi's Ghost Mansion for around hour, you unlock two bonus stages: the store room with knights that make your Wii remote vibrate to throw you off, and the roof level (which has like 8 Monita robots).

Answer (score 0):

Donkey Kong Crash Cource ~ Beat A Level Twice To Unlock The Next Level. There Are Four Total